# Android Emulator WARNING:

Tags: android, android-emulator

every time I compiled the program opens a new emulator

say this error

```
014-02-16 22:48:10 - Calculator] Android Launch!
[2014-02-16 22:48:10 - Calculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-16 22:48:10 - Calculator] Performing com.goldapp.calculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-02-16 22:48:11 - Calculator] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'dead' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-02-16 22:48:11 - Calculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Dead'
[2014-02-16 22:48:12 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2014-02-16 22:48:12 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\isrra_000\.android\avd\Dead.avd/sdcard.img
[2014-02-16 22:48:12 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2014-02-16 22:48:12 - Calculator] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2014-02-16 22:48:12 - Calculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Eclipse cannot connect to the running instance of the Emulator. Before running the application from the Eclipse, make sure that the Emulator instance is connectable. To do this:

- Switch to DDMS perspective [image: Switching to DDMS perspective]
- Check if the emulator is visible in the list of devices in the Devices tab

  - If it is not listed, reset adb from the drop down menu on the right side of the Devices tab [image: Rest adb]

It may show some errors while resetting the adb and the adb tries to enumerate the emulators/devices available. You can ignore it and wait for the emulator being shown in the Devices tab. Once it is listed, the application should run without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check the "Wipe user data" in the AVD and run it. If that won't help end adb process ( alt-ctrl-del --> start task manager and in the process tab find adb.exe to close it). Restart eclipse and it should work then.

If not try navigating to the folder mentioned in the error message (in your case C:\Users\isrra_000.android\avd\Dead.avd/) and (on Windows) there will be several folders whose names end in .lock, delete those and restart your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are normally displayed when you're trying to run two instances of the same AVD at the same time.

Each instance must have its own writable /data and /sdcard partitions, otherwise really bad things will happen (corruption of data files and general emulated system crashes).

To protect against this, the emulator detects multiple instances of the same AVD, then prints this message, it will also copy the current /data and /sdcard partitions to temporary files that are destroyed when you exit it (this is why it says "Changes will not persist.").

So in the end:

- The warnings are here to inform you that you're trying to run the same AVD twice.
- Doing so is safe, but any changes you do in the second AVD will be lost when you
  exit the emulator. Any change you perform in the first AVD instance will be saved to
  disk though.

If you want to run multiple instances of the same system at the same time, it's better to create several AVDs with the same settings, but different names.